# Android:Sax Parser returns half string sometimes?

Tags: android, saxparser

there are almost 50 items out of that one or two items string return half value,
this is my string in which i am getting half string value

```
<ques>On what base, the states have representation in the Rajya Sabha?</ques>

public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            value = new String(ch, start, length);

}
```

in this way i am fetching the value, all the value comes perfect except one or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal. SAX parsers [do not guarantee to deliver the whole character data at once](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#characters%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) (especially if whitespace is in between, like newline chars).

You have to design your code so that it handles `characters(..)` being called multiple times in a row.

Comment: but y it happens only some times not every time